# tried to edit framework-res.apk on kyocera rise stuck in bootloop

Tags: boot-loop

Earlier this month I got a Kyocera Rise.

I got it rooted the first minute I got it and decided I wanted to edit the `framework-res.apk` file. I extracted it, edited it, and trying to replace it, root explorer force closed. I was unable to open any application because I kept getting this (the application com.android.(so and so) isn't responding) error.

I stupidly restarted the phone, forgetting that I could have adb pushed my backup `framework-res.apk` file. This phone has a recovery system that doesn't allow flashing updates. The bootloader is locked and Kyocera has yet to release an update, therefore we have no idea how updates are flashed. Any help at all is very appreciated :)

Comment: Can you access the device via ADB while in recovery mode? Some devices have that enabled there by default.

Comment: Not sure but i will try that.....    how do i know it is connected to the adb shell

Comment: Running `adb devices` should list it as available. If not, it's not detected. But the latter could also mean driver issues (Windows: check Windows device manager; Linux: check output of `lsusb`).

Comment: ok i am about to try that right now

Comment: nope, nothing... just gave me a blank line